# jQuery 1.7.1 error with isEmpty in Internet Explorer 7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

One of my websites doesn't work correctly in Internet Explorer 7 or 8 (fine in modern browsers).

There is a section on the website that initiates a booking engine in a jQuery lightview modal but the following error is return in the console - any ideas?

```
SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'isEmpty' is null or undefined, not a Function
object jquery.min.js, line 3 character 4295
```

Comment: What is 'isEmpty'? Post relevant code

Comment: will post the code shortly

Comment: IE 7/8 has issues with compliance, and most likely does not have isEmpty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using either [jQuery.isEmptyObject()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) for checking objects or using the [empty selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) e.g.

```
$("p:empty");
```

If you haven't declared an 'isEmpty' function then you could use this one:

```
function isEmpty(aString) { 
    return (aString === null || aString === "" || typeof aString === 'undefined');
}
```